# MLE, a book: Statistical modelling and inference using likelihood

Tags: book-recommendation, binomial-distribution, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval

I have a problem with a likelihood interval;
[Here](http://62.182.86.140/main/824000/2b172c9b10954d846a1d43b53941a44d/Yudi%20Pawitan%20-%20In%20All%20Likelihood_%20Statistical%20Modelling%20and%20Inference%20Using%20Likelihood-Oxford%20University%20Press%2C%20USA%20%282001%29.pdf) on the page $74$ in the example $4.1$ they write:

**IN CASE the link doesn't download Please copy the link and paste it to your web browser.**

The likelihood interval at 15% cutoff (computed numerically) is $(0.50,0.96)$; since the likelihood is reasonably regular this is an approximate $95\%$ CI for $\theta$.

I do not follow what do they mean by this sentence: how did they come from 15% to 95% ?

[image]

Comment: That link leads to an unnamed server that doesn't respond.

Comment: @joriki Please see my **EDIT** and snippet included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is derived in Section $2.6$ of the book, “Likelihood-based intervals” (p. $35$ of the $2013$ paperback edition) under a normality assumption. The derivation uses a $\chi_1^2$ distribution, but you can actually get the same result using a Gaussian: $95\%$ of the probability lies within $\sqrt2\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(0.95)\approx1.96$ standard deviations of the mean, and at this point the probability density function has a value $\exp\left(-1.96^2/2\right)\approx0.15$ of its maximum value.

Comment: How have you arrived at the l.h.s. $\exp\left(-1.96^2/2\right)$ please ?

Comment: @user122424: That's just the exponential in the probability density function of a Gaussian distribution. The factors before the exponential cancel because they're the same at the maximum and at the cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an ad hoc approximation in relating likelihood intervals to traditional confidence intervals. It is has been observed in many "typical" situations that the 15% likelihood interval and the 95% confidence interval are roughly the same. Of course in relating them it brings up the questions "why would we use likelihood intervals to approximate confidence intervals!? Why not just use confidence intervals from the get go if that is what we want!?". The truth is that likelihood intervals are philosophically a different way of quantifying the uncertainty in an estimate. Historically they were a more popular choice, but over time the use of confidence intervals has become a much more common.

Comment: Great answer. Where can I learn more on "likelihood intervals" ? Perhaps also in the book cited in the OQ.

Comment: @user122424 thanks! I think there is a decent presentation on it in this book: https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/probability-statistical-inference/author/kalbfleisch/